# Searching for free OTA Server Host list name

Tags: ota

I have seen [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GR2ZXyPaqMo):

[Over The Air programming Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GR2ZXyPaqMo)

For programming the Arduino modules via internet  OTA system, so I have tried the [adafruit](https://io.adafruit.com) account and don't find the **AIO_KEY** part [on it](https://accounts.adafruit.com/users/security), ( as you can see below):

[image]

So I like to know about other web server systems for testing this option on the Arduino module (for me is ESP8266 01!).

So please suggest some free internet website as alternative options  like suggested site via above video ( adafruit).

The codes for making the esp8266 ready to accept the OTA process is accessible [here](https://github.com/techiesms/Over-The-Air-Programming/blob/master/OTA.ino).

Note: Also the https://io.adafruit.com/ server have some Problem right now:

So if possible I like to know is any safe methods exist for the interrupt and server problem
situation like this ([adafruit 503 error, seen below](https://www.uptimia.com/website-availability-test/e98da71a)) during the Arduino  OTA programming?

[image]

**Update**:

I have found the link of adafruit **OTA_Key** :

https://io.adafruit.com/ss1/dashboards/<Your_acount_Name>

[image]

Thanks.